# Data overrides by merge operation in hibernate in multi process scenario

Tags: hibernate, jpa, concurrentmodification

I have one table which is getting updated by two different process running at the same time. I am using DynamicUpdate annotation on my entities. I am facing following issue,

1. process 1 read data with status A
2. process 2 read data with status A while process 1 is running but not completed.
3. process 2 completed and update status B (using dynamic update on status column)
4. process 1 completed and update other columns but also change the status back to A. (process 1 is using dynamic update and not update status column)

Please suggest the possible reason for the above behaviour. Kindly note that I am using JPA + hibernate, and Spring transactions.

Any quick pointer will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by using separate `@Version` attribute on that entity. So, when process 1 and process 2 will work on same entity. If any one update the row, version will automatically incremented. and when another process tends to update the same row then it will find a mismatch of version and will throw an optimistic exception and you can simply catch the exception and may be show an error message to user containing specific error for that reason like `ooops sorry. someone has updated the row already`.

so, simply add an attribute like this:
`@Version
int version;`

thats all.
hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I have problem as process 1 and 2 both are batch job and I can not discontinue any of them. Means I have to make sure both process 1 and 2 completed. May be some way to define priority for each process.